# Remove Item from an observable collection and Delete it later

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an class called Receiving as a property bound to a window that allows users to edit.  Within that class is an observable collection called ReceivingDetails bound to a dataGrid.  The ReceivingDetails are also bound to textboxes for adding and editing.

When I need to add an item, it is simple:

```
theReceiving.ReceivingDetails.Add(new ReceivingDetails());
```

Nothing is saved until the user clicks SAVE.  When that happens I check for dirty on the parent and children and build a TRANSACTION, then commit.  I want all to roll back on failure.  Working great..

Now I need to delete details as well.  I'm trying to wrap my head around removing the item so that the binding will show it gone, but not really deleting the item until SAVE.

If I simply remove it from the collection, it will not be there to iterate through and physically delete.

I'm thinking of writing a special Receiving.DeleteDetail() method or something which would remove it from the observablecollection and save it to a list of "deleted details"... then when the receiving is saved, loop through the "Deleted details" list and run a SP to really delete them.

Am I on track, or is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

**UPDATE - Some of the Code:**

XAML for the datagri.  Note that it is bound to an observable collection within theReceiving.  thrReceiving is a PublicProperty on the window.

```
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                Name="dataGridReceivingDetails"
                AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                AlternationCount="2" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding theReceiving.ReceivingDetails, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            </DataGrid>
```

Here is the OC within the Receiving Class:

```
private ObservableCollection<ReceivingDetail> _ReceivingDetails;
/// <summary>
/// A List of the associated Shipment Details 
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<ReceivingDetail> ReceivingDetails
{
    get { return _ReceivingDetails; }
    set { _ReceivingDetails = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I hope that helps a bit...

Comment: Hi pStan, possible to post a bit more code? Hard for you to wrap your head around the problem, for me it's hard to wrap my head around what the problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of possible solutions to this.

1. You can store the original list and show a copy of it. Then run a compare on the two lists.
2. You can do what you suggested and offload all of the deleted into a separate list to be parsed through
3. You can add a property to the model that marks it as deleted and then only show a view of the dataset that excludes the items marked as deleted.

Option 1 actually has a lot of edge cases and might be annoying to implement depending on how deep you are checking. Option 2 is potentially the simplest as all you have to do is run through the deleted list on persist, or add back to the list on cancel. Option 3 is even simpler, however it requires adding UI logic to the model and is considered dirty.

All said and done, I personally would just go with option 2 for the simplicity factor.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the quick answer and options.  I'm leaning towards option 2.